# Cannot launch twitter oauth function in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, oauth, ngcordova

First question on stack overflow, will try to get it right. I am having trouble with a Twitter oauth in an Ionic app, using libraries cordova, and ng-cordova-oath amongst others.

I have succesfully managed a linkedin, facebook and google auth, retrieving data from user profiles on login, but this one has me beat.

I *think* the syntax is ok, as my alerts run in the browser, but when i emulate on android to test the logins, i am getting no response from the twitter login, success or failure.

I have triple checked the twitter developer site for my apps settings, am using the callback url "http://localhost/callback". I have tried overriding the callback uri in ng-cordova-oauth to a live url, and adjusting the matching setting in the developer console,  as this wasn't working for my linked in login, but i am not even reaching the callback part of the flow.

Index.html:

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Relevant block from app.js where libraries are provided:

`angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngCordovaOauth', 'ui.router', 'app.controllers'])`

controllers.js:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

    .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth, $http) {
        $scope.twitterLogin = function(){

            alert("running twitterLogin()"); // Alert works

            $cordovaOauth.twitter(
                "P1E***************", /* Client ID */
                "3et**************************************") /* Client Secret */ 
            .then(function(result){

                 alert("result token recieved"); /* Not running, can't access result to get token */

            }, function(error){
                alert("Error getting result token"); /* Not running, runs in browser when not emulated, of course the login process can't be tested in the browser */
            });

        alert("Oauth finished"); // Not running, reaches here in browser after failed login, but never reaches here in emulator
    }
});
```

login.html:

```
<div class="inline">
    <img src="img/loginTwitter.png" ng-click="twitterLogin()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Did you wrap your template with <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">

Comment: It should be index.html or index.htm

Comment: No, should i have? The other functions for the 3 working social media logins are all in the same controller, and they work fine

Comment: It is index.html, sorry a typo, i will edit now

Comment: Ravi from what i can see i only need ng-controller directive if i want to use variables from my js in my html

Comment: Yes. Since, you have a click event ng-click="twitterLogin()" and twitterLogin function is implemented in "LoginCtrl", you should wrap ng-controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved! The problem for me, if anybody else comes across it, is that i was using the wrong version of the sha1.js library. The version that is required to work with ng-cordova-oauth is the version 1 branch, and not the master branch, on the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
    // Did you load angularjs in scripts?
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sha1.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div class="inline">
        <img src="img/loginTwitter.png" ng-click="twitterLogin()" />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Your template should look something like this.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, i can't add to my index.html as this is not the template i am using. So i added ng-controller="LoginCtrl" to the <ion-content> element that holds all of my buttons. If this was required, then shnouldn't my other three logins on the same template be failing too? It didn't work..